# Heroku: deploying minio server with Dockerfile CMD failure

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, minio

I am trying to deploy my minio server to heroku.  This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM minio/minio
ENV MINIO_ACCESS_KEY="xxxxxx"
ENV MINIO_SECRET_KEY="xxxxxxxx"
CMD ["server", "/data"]
EXPOSE 9000
```

**This works locally** when I build and run it through docker (using these commands:)

```
docker build . -t testheroku
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 testheroku
```

The Dockerfile is the only file in the directory.

Then, I try to push it to heroku.  I followed the commands on the [heroku docker instruction page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime) to install the heroku container plugin, login, etc.  Then, I pushed my app with: `heroku container:push web --app APP_NAME`

When I visit the app, I get an application error in browser.  This is what the heroku logs display:

```
2017-09-21T02:24:47.589576+00:00 app[api]: Deployed web (26b84915ed48) by user []
2017-09-21T02:24:47.589576+00:00 app[api]: Release v28 created by user []
2017-09-21T02:24:48.241050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-09-21T02:24:49.480733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `server /data`
2017-09-21T02:24:51.961825+00:00 app[web.1]: ‘server /data’ is not a minio sub-command. See ‘minio --help’.
2017-09-21T02:24:52.056706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-09-21T02:24:52.064400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-09-21T02:24:52.938136+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=APP_NAME.herokuapp.com request_id=80ddd6f8-c053-4ff6-b4c9-fdb0ce8a48a5 fwd="67.245.14.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-09-21T02:24:54.319660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=APP_NAME.herokuapp.com request_id=9988b6af-8a91-4e77-9bd4-c79c9e2ec24c fwd="67.245.14.153" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

For those unfamiliar with minio, some explanation of `‘server /data’ is not a minio sub-command. See ‘minio --help’.`: this shows when you run the minio command with an argument that isn't a minio command. For example,

```
./minio sadf
‘sadf’ is not a minio sub-command. See ‘minio --help’.
```

So what heroku is telling me is that it's interpreting the CMD line from my Dockerfile, not as it should (which is with `server` as the minio subcommand and `/data` as its argument) but instead, if you notice the quotation marks, heroku is smashing the two pieces together and attempting to use the whole string as a minio subcommand - hence the error message.  It's trying to run the command `minio 'server /data'` instead of `minio server /data`

Has anyone seen this kind of behavior from heroku before with a Dockerfile?  How can I make sure that the CMD line gets interpreted correctly, and not as one full string?  I assume this is a heroku issue because it runs fine locally.  Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Push a simple image and try testing different CMD on a basic alpine image and see if that is really the case

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue that seemed to be caused by having other ENTRYPOINTS in the parent layers. To solve this, I added `ENTRYPOINT []` above my CMD and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same issue.
This Dockerfile works fine.

```
FROM minio/minio:RELEASE.2022-01-08T03-11-54Z.fips

ENV MINIO_ROOT_USER=XXXXXX
ENV MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXXXX

EXPOSE 9000
EXPOSE 9001

ENTRYPOINT ["minio"]
CMD ["server","/data","--console-address",":9001"]
```